# Why a radiobuttonlist always take a new row?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, layout, interface, radiobuttonlist

This is a question about layout. I'm developing a .net page, whenever I add a radiobuttonlist right after a label, it comes down to next row. But in the code side, it still within the same row. The problem is if you browse it in IE, it comes down to the next row. I am sure the width of both label and radiobuttonlist is not oversized. What's the reason and how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

RadioButtonList by default renders as table. You can change set the property **RepeatLayout="Flow"** and it will be rendered in span.

[RepeatLayout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatlayout.aspx)

[Different ways it can render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

Add a property to your radiobuttonlist

RepeatDirection="Horizontal"

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
        ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" style="display:inline">
        <asp:ListItem>asdf</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>sdfg</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

this will solve your problem. CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

You can set it's display style to be inline:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList
    ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" style="display:inline">
    <asp:ListItem>asdf</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>sdfg</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Warning:  Purists will scream that information should be in a CSS class somewhere else.

Comment: in ASP.net, nobody can hear you scream.

Comment: especially when the solution that you propose doesn't work :-P

Comment: Yes it does, perhaps you didn't read the original post carefully.  BTW:  Replying to a post 7 months old is considered necro-posting by many.

Answer (score 0):

if you have apply css on page, then it is hard to maintain style of radiobuttonlist.

Mine was fix with below code

```
#radiobuttonlist label
{
   vertical-align: super;
}
```