# asp:radiobuttonlist css style

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have created an asp.net website using the default .net template and my radio button lists have huge radio buttons.

Like so:

[image]

My question is, how can I get the text inline with the radio buttons and also have the button be as small as possible?

I know it is css related but unsure which is responsible for that.

Here is the css:

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    /*a:hover {
        background-color: #FF3A8F;
    }*/

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1280px;/*960px;*/
}

.gridview {
    width: 100%; 
    /*word-wrap:break-word;*/
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .featured + .main-content {
        background: url("../Images/heroAccent.png") no-repeat;
    }

header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px; 
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */
.featured {
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        background-color: #7ac0da;
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        color: #3e5667;
        padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
    }

        .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
            color: #fff;
        }

        .featured p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }

        ol.round li.zero {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.one {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.two {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.three {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.four {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.five {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.six {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.seven {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.eight {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.nine {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
        }

/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

    aside ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

        aside ul li {
            background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
        }

.label {
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* login page */
#loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

    #socialLoginForm h2 {
        margin-bottom:  5px;
    }

fieldset.open-auth-providers {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

    fieldset.open-auth-providers button {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

/* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

/* forms */
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    fieldset legend {
        display: none;
    }

    fieldset ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        fieldset ol li {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

    label {
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    label.checkbox {
        display: inline;
    }

    input, textarea {
        border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    textarea {
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 500px;
    }

        input:focus, textarea:focus {
            border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"] {
            background: transparent;
            border: inherit;
            width: auto;
        }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;

    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a:hover {
            color: #333;
        }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content,
    .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ol.round li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }

            ol.round li.zero,
            ol.round li.one,
            ol.round li.two,
            ol.round li.three,
            ol.round li.four,
            ol.round li.five,
            ol.round li.six,
            ol.round li.seven,
            ol.round li.eight,
            ol.round li.nine {
                background: none;
            }

     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }



    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
/* END: Mobile Styles */
```

The aspx code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblRecordStatus" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblRecordStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" TextAlign="Left">
        <asp:ListItem>ALL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Active</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>On Hold</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Could you also give the generated HTML-source of the radio button list? As the css is doing its work on that.

Comment: Check this solution out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670479/display-radiobuttonlist-inline

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been able to do what you want with the following code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblRecordStatus" RepeatDirection="Vertical" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblRecordStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" TextAlign="Right" CssClass="inline-rb">
    <asp:ListItem>ALL</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Active</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>On Hold</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

(note the 'TextAlign' and 'CssClass' changed).

In the *.css file:

```
.inline-rb input[type="radio"] {
    width: auto;
}

.inline-rb label {
    display: inline;
}
```

And the result:
[image: What I got]

Answer (score 2):

In my case below CSS style helped:

```
.RadioButtonList
{
  vertical-align:super;  
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton9" CssClass="radiobtn" Text="Get" />
```

**CSS**

```
.radiobtn input[type="radio"] {
    width: 30px;
    Height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

[radio button list as buttons with selected border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxiIM.jpg)

```css
.easy-radio2 input[type="radio"]  {
  display: none!important;
}
.easy-radio2 label {
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #F6F7F9;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.easy-radio2 input[type="radio"] + label {
  color: #c6c6c6;
  border: 1.5px solid transparent;
  font-weight: 400; 
}
.easy-radio2 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: 1.5px solid #131f52;
  color: #131f52;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CssClass="easy-radio2" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" >YES</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" >NO</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).